# Netbeans is failing to build (How do I point it to my new Open MPI library?)

Tags: gcc, configuration, netbeans, openmpi

I am doing C development using Netbeans on OS X and my project fails to build, stating "...this installation of Open MPI was not compiled with Fortran 90 support"

I have installed a newer gcc and Open MPI (along side the default versions), and I can build using them via make on a command line. This leads me to believe that Netbeans is using the default Open MPI installation (which did not have fortran support). If I am correct, how do I get it to use the new installation? I told Netbeans about the other compilers via the Tool Collection Manager (File->Project Properties->Build->Tool Collection->[...]). However, I do not know of a way to tell it about Open MPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution. This solution exists in two parts.

1) I reran configure on the command line for my project and specified full paths for MPICC and MPIFC. This solved the problem of getting Netbeans to use the right mpicc compiler. However, it created another issue: the mpif90 wrapper could not find gfortran.

2) I altered the 'GUI environment' PATH variable to put gfortran in my path using the /etc/launchd.conf method found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x).

After a reboot, Netbeans compiles my project. So, I'm claiming success.